# ios stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding convert not corrected

Tags: ios, nsstringencoding

I have some content like `2ofsjw0234lnc.jpg\t2m03fcsmaokwf.jpg\n` want to encode as a url Parameter，so I use code like bellowed.

```
NSString * attachsString = [_attachments stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the output is `2ofsjw0234lnc.jpg%5ct2m03fcsmaokwf.jpg%5cn`
it is not my wanted, `2ofsjw0234lnc.jpg%092m03fcsmaokwf.jpg%0d%0a`, the Escape character are not convert as i wanted. only "\" have been converted.

so what could you give some advice?

Comment: What is wrong with the output? It will still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `\t` in a string literal, then at compile time, this gets converted to a tab. Then  `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` would convert the tab to `%09`. However, if at runtime, the string has the two characters `\t`, then this is not treated any different than any other two characters. In this case, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` simply sees the backslash and converts it to `%5c`.

If you want to convert `\t` or `\n` strings (not characters) at runtime, then you should use:

```
// note the double backslash for the tab
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\t" withString:@"%09"];
```

Repeat for the `\n`.